# Debugging After Effect Scripts

Tags: javascript, debugging, after-effects

I have an After Effects script that wont work in unless I am running CS6 version. I need it to be usable in older versions of After Effects, but I have no experience with scripting for After Effects. I'm web dev, but I have no idea where to even begin the debugging process for this type of jsx script. Would someone kindly point me in a direction to start the debugging process?

Answer (score 0):

In order to check scripts for older versions of AE, you need to have:

- Whatever older version(s) of AE installed,
- ExtendScript Toolkit (ESTK) installed, and make sure it "sees" the version(s) of AE you are running (by checking the "target application" popup in the upper left; *it may be that you'll have to install older versions of ESTK to work with older versions of AE* -- thankfully it is a small app)

Frankly, I rarely use ESTK; I usually debug by other means, but if you're used to various debugging tools available in other programs, you should be able to utilize what ESTK offers (breakpoints, results of script execution, etc.).

Comment: but I wouldn't advise going too far back to early versions of AE ... maybe CS5

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying, I was able to debug for CS6in ESTK, but when i tried to debug for AE CC2015 it said "Cannot launch target Adobe After Effects CC 2015 (13.5)!" do you know what that would mean?

Comment: Hmm. This sounds like a problem that appeared in v13.1, which Adobe fixed with an update. I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with this problem. This happens with even the simplest code? Could you post an example?